# In Awesome-cv template, how can I change all upper case letters to a mix of lower and upper case letters?

Tags: awesome-cv

For example in the sample format, the degree is all in upper case letters:

POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology) 
"B.S. IN COMPUTER SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING"

I would like to change it to:
"B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering"

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

I obtained the template from Sharelatex: [Awesome-CV template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv).

Also, following is a snippet of the template (it uses the awesome-cv.cls file):

Main file: Resume.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

%%% Override a directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')
\fontdir[fonts/]

%%% Configure a directory location for sections
\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}
\usepackage{import}

%%% Essentials
\name{Claud D.}{Park}
\address{246-1002, Gwangmyeongmayrouge Apt. 86, Cheongna lime-ro, Seo-gu, Incheon-si, 22738, Rep. of KOREA}
\mobile{(+82) 10-9030-1843} 
%%% Social
\email{posquit0.bj@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{posquit0}
\linkedin{posquit0}
%%% Optionals
\position{Software Engineer{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert}

%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {Claud D. Park~~~·~~~Résumé}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

% Import contents
\import{\sectiondir}{education.tex}

\end{document}
```

Supporting file: education.tex

```
\cvsection{Education}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering}
    {POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology)}
    {Pohang, S.Korea}
    {Mar. 2010 - PRESENT}
    {
      \begin{cvitems}
        \item {Got a Chun Shin-Il Scholarship which is given to promising students in CSE Dept.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting of the first argument of `\cvitem` in `awesome-cv` is controlled by `\entrypositionstyle` which is defined as follows in `awesome-cv.sty`:

```
\newcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{graytext} #1}}
```

To get rid of the all caps (`\scshape`), one can use the following command

```
\renewcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{graytext} #1}}
```

in the preamble of the document as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\renewcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{graytext} #1}}

\begin{document}
\cvsection{Education}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering}
    {POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology)}
    {Pohang, S.Korea}
    {Mar. 2010 - PRESENT}
    {
      \begin{cvitems}
        \item {Got a Chun Shin-Il Scholarship which is given to promising students in CSE Dept.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

[image]